# Convert video MP4 audio to MP3 using C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, data-conversion

I have some videos in MP4 format and I'm trying to extract the audio from them.

My code is:

```
public static void Converter(string toConvert)
{
    toConvert = VideoFile + ".mp4";

    var join = VideoFile.Split("-").ToList();

    VideoFile = string.Format("{0} - {1}", join[0], join[1]);

    var outputFile = VideoFile + ".mp3";
    var mp3Out = "";

    var ffmpegProcess = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            FileName = Directory,
            Arguments = " -i " + toConvert + " -vn -f mp3 -ab 320k output " + outputFile
        }
    };

    ffmpegProcess.Start();
    ffmpegProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    mp3Out = ffmpegProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();

    if (!ffmpegProcess.HasExited)
    {
        ffmpegProcess.Kill();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(mp3Out);
}
```

However, I get this error message:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'

Any Ideas?

Comment: Go get some permission first, of course.

Comment: `Directory` contains the **full** path to `ffmpeg` ?

Comment: Yes this contains the full path - 
@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Videos\

Comment: Is it a windows service or console app ?

Comment: `FileName` sholld be the path to `ffmpeg` not to the video: Ex `d:\tmp\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20180119-07a96b6-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe`

Comment: @Stormcloak this is a console app.

Comment: It seems that you are not allowed to execute cmd.exe. Would you try to execute the program as Administrator ?

Comment: @Stormcloak I've just added a manifest file and I'm awaiting the build 
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Answer (score 2):

From the comments I understand that the `Directory` variable contains te path to the video and you set this on the `FileName` for the process start info. `FielName` of `StartInfo` should contain the path to the ffmpeg executable. Ex:

```
public static string FFMpegPath { get; private set; } = @"d:\tmp\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20180119-07a96b6-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";

var ffmpegProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        ....
        FileName = FFMpegPath
    }
};
```

If I set the `FileName` to a directory (ex: `d:\Videos\`) I get the same error as you

Comment: Cool I'll give this a whirl.

Comment: Just converted a file on my PC so it should work :) careful though .. if the output file already exists, ffmpeg will promt you to override, so it will block waiting for input ;)